# Two divs side by side inside wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place two divs side by side with 20px margin between them. Divs are inside wrapper, which width is 800px. Left div is 250px and right div is 550px, but of course if I add 20px margin between them, total width is increasing over 800px. Is there any way to force right div width to be 550px - 20px margin?

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.right {
    width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
        </div>

        <div class="right">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I mean do I have to decrease width manually or is there any better solutions?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ytsvd77f/

Comment: Please add your code on the jsfiddle and send the link for more efficient answers.

Comment: To make it simpleIn response to your code.. add display: flex; in your wrapper.
Let me know if it works

Comment: Is there a reason it would not just be making the width 530px? Am I the only one who can do math in my head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `calc(550px - 20px)` as `width` of right div.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.right {
  width: -moz-calc(550px - 20px);
  width: -webkit-calc(550px - 20px);
  width: -o-calc(550px - 20px);
  width: calc(550px - 20px);
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about **calc**! Is this best practice?

Comment: I would go with this one, you can also do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/929/ with padding.

Comment: Why would use `calc()` with static values of the same unit, instead of just `530px`?

Comment: calc makes no  sense here

Answer (score 0):

If you add display:flex in your wrapper it will work perfectly and I guess you will understand better.
Check it out the css.

```
    .wrapper {
       max-width: 800px;
       height: 400px;
       background-color: green;
       margin: 0 auto;
       display: flex;
    }
```